# How to access a jpanel(in the JDesktopPane) from a JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I want to set access of a jpanel(which is in the JDesktopPane ) from JInternalFrame, I set it to public but no way its gives 'null' when I do some test like that:

```
JDesktop frameP = new JDesktop();
frameP.jPanel1.setVisible(true); //This is what I want but it doesn't work

System.out.println("Name " + frameP.jPanel1.getName());
```

so the last line gives me null that it means that he doesn't get the JPanel.

I try also that code:

```
 for(int k=0; k<frameP.getContentPane().getComponentCount();k++ ){
             if(frameP.getContentPane().getComponent(k)instanceof  JPanel){
                 JPanel pnl = (JPanel) frameP.getContentPane().getComponent(k);
                 if(pnl.getName().equals("jPanel1")){
                     pnl.setVisible(true);
                 }
                 System.out.println("Nom pnl: " +pnl.getName()); // That gives null too
             }
         }
```

Any help please?

Comment: What is a JDesktop?  Presumably this is your class, but you haven't provided the code for it, so any answers from us would just be guesses.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to use JDesktopPanes, you don't add JPanels directly to them. You add your JPanels to a JInternalFrame, then add this JIF to the JDesktopPane, which is in turn added to a JFrame.

Comment: JDesktop that's just the name of the JDesktopPane. I use the palette to add controls that's why but the panel is on JDesktop and I want to access it from the JInternalFrame

Comment: No, JDesktop is not "just the name of the JDesktopPane".  Apparently you've subclassed it (not the same thing) and you haven't shown us the code for it.

Comment: "I use the palette to add controls that's why but the panel is on JDesktop and I want to access it from the JInternalFrame"... Instead of trying to decipher this comment, I'll just point you to the tutorial: [How To Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Comment: sorry I misunderstand you, JDesktop is the JFrame that contains the JInternalFrames it just contains the JMenuBar + JPanel and JDesktopPane . Which code should I show?

Answer (score 0):

I just resolve that problem I do that:

```
JDesktop.jpnlGauche.setVisible(false);
JDesktop.jpnlHaut.setVisible(false);
```